# SQLite3 weird insert speed issue

Tags: performance, sqlite, insertion, slowdown

I have two tables as follows (no indices):

```
CREATE TABLE dag(
id integer primary key,
v integer,
e integer,
cc integer,
h integer,
w integer,
ls integer,
le blob, 
am blob);

CREATE TABLE additional_comp(
id integer primary key,
did integer,
t integer,
ubd integer,
lbd integer,
tlbd integer);
```

My program (in C) generates a few million entries (stored in two balanced binary search trees in RAM) and tries to insert them into these two tables. I have 50000 insertions per transaction and output time used in a log, here it is:

> dag has 1573505 records
>   comp has 2375074 records
>   db_dag has 5 records
>   db_comp has 11 records
>   insert dags, Mon Nov  6 15:42:11 2017
>   **0 rows done, Mon Nov  6 15:42:11 2017
>
>   50000 rows done, Mon Nov  6 16:45:57 2017
>
>   100000 rows done, Mon Nov  6 18:25:22 2017
>
>   150000 rows done, Mon Nov  6 20:29:01 2017
>
>   200000 rows done, Mon Nov  6 22:36:13 2017
>
>   250000 rows done, Tue Nov  7 03:52:03 2017
>
>   300000 rows done, Tue Nov  7 10:01:38 2017
>
>   350000 rows done, Tue Nov  7 17:33:52 2017
>
>   400000 rows done, Tue Nov  7 22:49:14 2017
>
>   450000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 06:06:28 2017
>
>   500000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 11:33:49 2017
>
>   550000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 16:53:04 2017
>
>   600000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:08:46 2017**
>   650000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:10:16 2017
>   700000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:11:19 2017
>   750000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:12:17 2017
>   800000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:13:03 2017
>   850000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:13:49 2017
>   900000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:14:48 2017
>   950000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:15:30 2017
>   1000000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:16:11 2017
>   1050000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:16:51 2017
>   1100000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:17:43 2017
>   1150000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:18:26 2017
>   1200000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:19:13 2017
>   1250000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:20:14 2017
>   1300000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:20:59 2017
>   1350000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:21:43 2017
>   1400000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:22:21 2017
>   1450000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:22:57 2017
>   1500000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:23:33 2017
>   1550000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:03 2017
>   .....done
>   insert comps, Wed Nov  8 17:24:13 2017
>   1600000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:21 2017
>   1650000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:22 2017
>   1700000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:23 2017
>   1750000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:23 2017
>   1800000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:23 2017
>   1850000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:24 2017
>   1900000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:24 2017
>   1950000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:24 2017
>   2000000 rows done, Wed Nov  8 17:24:25 2017

Note that it was extremely slow (several hours per 50000 insertions) at the beginning (bold part), but suddenly sped up (a couple minutes per 50000 insertions). Then for the comp table, the speed was quite stable.

Another instance of the same program was running on another core (inserting into a **different copy** of the database), no other "big" programs running on the machine. The same slow-->fast pattern happened with it as well around (but not exactly at) the same time. This makes me feel like that something happened before Nov 8 17:08 that slows down the whole machine.

But the machine has 16 cores (as mentioned, only 2 was in use) and 300GB RAM (about 2% was in use). The question is, what kind of things may have happened that make sqlite slow down this much? Or if it was not the machine, was I doing something wrong with sqlite? Any suggestion/idea is appreciated.

Comment: Are you inserting the `id` values, or using autoincrement? In the first case, in which order?

Comment: Yes, I'm inserting the `id` values. Each entry is assigned a unique (auto-incremented) `id` when it is generated then it is inserted into the tree based on another key (combination of `v`, `e`, etc., so it can be searched from the tree efficiently later). So eventually the in-order traversal will prepare insertions in some indefinite order according to `id`.  Is sqlite checking for criteria of primary keys making insertions slow? But why did it speed up later?

Comment: Insertion works fastest if the row is appended at the end of the table, i.e., if the `rowid` is larger than all previous ones. I don't know how your ID values are generated.